# How to specify the filename of a data-URI resource in an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html, data-uri

I want to implement client side downloadable file using javascript and am using DATA URI to dynamically create the file in client side using following way:

```
<a href="data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,Col1%2CCol2%2CCol3%0AVal1%2CVal2%2CVal3%0AVal11%2CVal22%2CVal33%0AVal111%2CVal222%2CVal333">Download CSV</a>
```

However, the downloaded file doesn't have a name. I saw some solutions on stackoverflow where 'download' attribute can be used but I need to support old browsers so I cannot use this.

Comment: I think you might be out of luck if you're looking for a solution that is both client-side and supported in old (NCSA Mosaic et al?) browsers. Why not use the download attribute which will work at least for browsers that support it? Setting up the download on the server side would be the best approach.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the fact that [*not* all browsers](http://caniuse.com/download) *which support data-URIs* honor the [`<a download>`](http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute) attribute: (how) can such behavior, of specifying a filename, be emulated in this case?

Answer (score 6):

You can easily adapt this piece of code to your needs:

```
//Generate a file name
    var fileName = "List_";
    //this will remove the blank-spaces from the title and replace it with an underscore
    fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g,"_");   

    //Initialize file format you want csv or xls
    var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);

    // Now the little tricky part.
    // you can use either>> window.open(uri);
    // but this will not work in some browsers
    // or you will not get the correct file extension    

    //this trick will generate a temp <a /> tag
    var link = document.createElement("a");    
    link.href = uri;

    //set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
    link.style = "visibility:hidden";
    link.download = fileName + ".csv";

    //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Answer (score 1):

`download` attribute of `a` tag now specifies the name of the downloaded file:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-hyperlink-download

Answer (score 0):

Take a look the following link. It appears to let you download client side generated data and specify a filename.

https://code.google.com/p/download-data-uri/

Comment: He specified both client side and that the download attribute won't work in the "old" browsers he needs to support.

Comment: Try it yourself - however the description states that yes, it's intended to work in Chrome.

Comment: I was talking about the content disposition in client side uri. I guess it doesn't work. As far as your edited solution is concerned, i think it will work.

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com/download this patch is no longer needed for Chrome (since 14 ~ 2011). I'm not sure if this patch will work in IE (9/10+), Safari, or other current browsers without the download-attribute support (as it was created specifically for Chrome < 14), but I suppose it doesn't hurt to try ..